# Why the value of a variable is wrongly pressed when a button is press in applet?

Tags: java, button, applet

I have a code in which there is a variable `v` whose default value is 0 . I also have 2 buttons : `ok` and `nope`. Using my code, when `ok` is pressed, the value of `v` should be 1 and when `nope` is pressed the value of `v` should be 2. But in both the cases it is printing the value of `v` as 2. Why is this? How can I correct it?

Edit : I did a minor mistake, I have corrected it, thanks to MadProgrammer.

```
import java.awt.*;
public class chk extends java.applet.Applet
{
    Button ok = new Button("OK!");
    Button nope = new Button("Nope");
    int v = 0;
    public void init()
    {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        add(ok);
        add(nope);
    }

    public boolean action(Event evt , Object arg)
    {
        if(evt.target instanceof Button)
        {
            check((Button)evt.target);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void check(Button b)
    {
        if(b == ok);
        {
            v= 1;
            repaint();
        }
        if(b == nope);
        {
            v=2;
            repaint();
        }
   }
   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
        g.drawString(""+v,40,40);
   }
   }
```

All help is appreciated. Please let me know if I've made any mistakes.

Comment: Wow, I've not seen that style of code for...a very long time. Any reason why you're using AWT over Swing (or even FX)?

Comment: 1. did you debug check() ?   
2. reference comparison (`b == ok`) is little dangerous

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at your `if` statements

```
    if(b == nope);
```

You've added a `;` at the end of each statement. This means that both blocks of code within the `{...}` braces are being executed regardless of what the `if` statements might want.  Remove the `;` from the end of each statement

Ps- Unless you have a very particular need to use raw AWT, I'd consider taking a look at Swing or if you're really adventurous, JavaFX, as they are more modern GUI APIs

Comment: @MadProgrammer, wow! I have been reviewing this code for a minute and have not seen this!

Comment: @AlexR I'm not sure why it stood it, but it just did :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer, i really appreciate ur eyes , i have been studding java from 3 months , but i never did this kind of mistake and therefore never gave much attention to it , thanz a lot , i had created a much lengthier program and did the same mistake , my problem which i was not able to solve from 3 days has been solved :)

Comment: @Darsh If you are satisfied with MadProgrammer's answer, you really should accept it by hitting the little green checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use deprecated method and use an `ActionListener` instead :

```
ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                v = 1;
                repaint();
            }
});
nope.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {               
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                v = 2;
                repaint();
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` COmparison is not considered good try something like this and As MadProgrammer said try removing `;` after if and else.

```
if(b.getLabel().equals("OK!"))
     {
       v=1;
       repaint();
      }
if(b.getLabel().equals("Nope"))
      {
        v=2;
        repaint();
      }
```